# MLSLABEL Oracle datatype

Tags: sql, oracle

Where can practically use this type?

[What is the MLSLABEL Oracle datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858682/what-is-the-mlslabel-oracle-datatype)

This theme is very old so it can have practical use of this type?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Are you using an old version of Oracle with Trusted Oracle that is using the data type?  Or are you interested in trying to create a new table using this type for some reason of purely academic interest?

Comment: The link in the question itself explains more. May be you can this http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0420__PL-SQL-Data-Types/MSLABEL.htm too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> MLSLABEL : The Oracle PL/SQL datatype MLSLABEL is used to store an
>   operating system label in binary format. It is used for Oracle Label
>   Security (which was earlier known as Trusted Oracle MLS RDBMS). The
>   maximum precision for MLSLABEL column is 255 bytes; its Datatype Code
>   is "105".

http://psoug.org/definition/MLSLABEL.htm